# Heterogenous tree in the application domain: How do I represent them?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, mvc, tree, database

## The Domain

I have three types of items in my domain: ItemA, ItemB, ItemC. (I can't use their real names.) ItemA has one attribute: thing_id. ItemB has 6 attributes: thing_id, name, description, state_id, a_number, a_status. ItemC has 5 attributes: name, description, state_id, creator_id, category_id. There is some overlap among the attributes of the things and they are conceptually similar, so I've been representing them using [STI](http://eewang.github.io/blog/2013/03/12/how-and-when-to-use-single-table-inheritance-in-rails/). However, I have a lot of null columns in the database, and I use validates_absence_of all over the place.

The items can have events on a calendar, represented by a model with an item_id. I initially tried to do polymorphic associations, but it made event creation impossible.

## The Tree

I need to represent the items in a tree-shaped hierarchy. The requirements for the tree are:

- ItemA cannot have a parent
- ItemA may have 0 or more children
- ItemB may have 0 or more parents
- ItemB may have 0 or more children
- ItemB cannot be the child of ItemC
- ItemC must have exactly 1 parent
- ItemC may have 0 or more children
- an item cannot be its own parent

Example Tree:

```
B1  A
 \ /
  B2
   \
    C
```

Right now I'm implementing the tree as a ItemGroup model with a group_id and a sub_item_id. The Item-ItemGroup association is a has_many for both groups and sub_items, and the items themselves are associated through a has_many :through for both groups and sub_items as well. Most of the tree requirements don't have validations attached to them. At times I need to access a whole sub tree. I'm using recursion to do that.

## The Code

**Item**

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :state, class_name: 'ItemState'
  has_many :events
  has_many :item_groups, foreign_key: 'sub_item_id', dependent: :destroy
  has_many :groups, through: :item_groups
  has_many :group_items, class_name: 'ItemGroup', foreign_key: 'group_id', dependent: :destroy
  has_many :sub_items, through: :group_items
  before_destroy :destroy_child_itemcs
  delegate :name, to: :state, prefix: true

  def destroy_child_itemcs
    itemcs.destroy_all
  end

  def itemcs
    sub_items.where(type: 'ItemC')
  end

  # Gets a subtree of ItemCs
  def itemc_rollup
    itemcs + sub_items.map(&:itemc_rollup).flatten
  end

  def has_group? item
    groups.exists? item
  end
  alias_method :sub_item_for?, :has_group?

  def group_for? item
    sub_items.exists? item
  end
  alias_method :has_sub_item?, :group_for?

  def has_sub_items?
    sub_items.exists?
  end

  def a?
    type == 'ItemA'
  end

  def b?
    type == 'ItemB'
  end

  def c?
    type == 'ItemC'
  end
end
```

**ItemA**

```
class ItemA < Item
  include ThingComponent
  belongs_to :thing
  validates :thing_id, presence: true, uniqueness: { scope: :type }
  validates_absence_of :creator_id, :category_id, :state_id, :a_status,
      :a_number, :name, :description

  def state_name
    ''
  end
end
```

**ItemB**

```
class ItemB < Item
  include ThingComponent
  belongs_to :thing
  validates_presence_of :state_id, :thing_id, :a_status
  validates_absence_of :creator_id, :category_id
  validates_uniqueness_of :thing_id, scope: :a_status
end
```

**ItemC**

```
class ItemC < Item
  belongs_to :category, class_name: 'ItemCategory'
  belongs_to :creator, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'creator_id'
  validates_absence_of :thing_id, :a_status, :a_number
  validates_presence_of :state_id, :creator_id, :category_id, :name

  def parent
    groups.take
  end
  alias_method :component, :parent

  def parent! component
    component.sub_items << self
  end
end
```

**ItemGroup**

```
class ItemGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group, class_name: 'Item'
  belongs_to :sub_item, class_name: 'Item'
  validates_presence_of :group, :sub_item
  validates_uniqueness_of :group, scope: :sub_item
  validate :group_must_not_be_sub_item

  private
  def group_must_not_be_sub_item
    if group_id == sub_item_id
      errors[:base] << "Parent can't be the same as its child"
    end
  end
end
```

**ThingComponent (holds methods common to ItemA and ItemB)**

```
module ThingComponent
  def has_sub_components?
    sub_items.exists?(type: %w(ItemA ItemB))
  end

  def sub_components
    sub_items.where(type: %w(ItemA ItemB))
  end

  # Gets a sub tree of ThingComponents
  def sub_component_rollup
    sub_components + sub_components.map(&:sub_component_rollup).flatten
  end

  def descendants_and_self
    sub_component_rollup << self
  end

  def component
    self
  end
end
```

## The Problems

I know there's a lot of problems with my code and I'm sure there's a better way to do it, but I don't know what that better way is. The big things that stand out to me as code smells:

- too many null database columns
- not enough validations of the tree requirements

## The Question

Given all that background, what is a better way to represent the items and the tree in domain and in the database?

Comment: You say an item can't be its own parent, but your example tree diagram has B as its own parent.

Comment: @MarkThomas I intended them to be different ItemBs. I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: It's a little tough to say anything definitive without knowing the concrete domain you're modelling (in abstract, yours is perhaps one of many solutions, but evaluating their merits might depend heavily on the specific problem at hand). Of course, if you can't be more specific, well, then that's the way it is. I will say though that - in abstract - you're likely on the right track with shared logic in modules, so perhaps it's mostly a matter or dropping STI. You'll get some duplication in the tables, yes, but none of the redundancy. More object composition, less actual inheritance.

Comment: +1 to @Flambino's comment.  You mention that you can't say what the items really are -- unfortunately it's nearly impossible to give valuable feedback without knowing the domain specifics.  My gut tells me that your solutions is overcomplicating things, but that's hardly more than a guess....